# INSERT INTO STATMENT ERRORS

Tags: ms-access

i have a **patientF** form opened, and i need to take one value **PatientNumber** in that record and append it as a new record in another table **FollowUpT** that is not related to the record source of the current form **patientT**.

so i write this in the sub routine Savebtn  on a click event.

```
 CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO FollowUpT (PatientNumber)" & Values(TempVars!PatientNumbervar)
```

but it keep giving me so many errors like too few parameters and others :(

help please

```
                                                                  .
```

Comment: Just move the closing bracket `"` at the end of the SQL string and remove the `&`, but did you store the `TempVar` variable first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO FollowUpT (PatientNumber) Values(TempVars!PatientNumbervar)"
```

or

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO FollowUpT (PatientNumber) Values(" & TempVars!PatientNumbervar & ")"
```

Comment: thanks june7, the 2nd one works perfectly 